# Why resharper adds // unsed comment to file

Tags: resharper-9.0

After cleaning up code with ctrl+E+C combination Resharper add the following two lines to my file

```
// unset
```

This happens only when using a custom cleanup profile. What may be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when the option "Update file header" is specified in reformat configuration, but file header is not configured.

This may happen when saving configs to team settings and moving between projects.